# npm install need root/Administrator

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am facing this error during running `npm install` command.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-63-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /media/DOCUMENT/plugin/node_modules/pg/node_modules/.bin/semver
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, symlink '/media/DOCUMENT/plugin/node_modules/pg/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, symlink '/media/DOCUMENT/plugin/node_modules/pg/node_modules/.bin/semver']
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: '/media/DOCUMENT/plugin/node_modules/pg/node_modules/.bin/semver' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/DOCUMENT/plugin/npm-debug.log
```

Please suggest me, how i can fix this issue. I tried some solution but no luck.
FYI, I tried by using `sudo npm install` and this didn't solve the issue.

**Update:**
  This works fine when the main code base resides in the home directory. Now everything working fine after put the project under the home directory of the user!

Thanks

Comment: `sudo npm install`  ?

Comment: Please try running the command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: I did but it's not working!

Comment: This works fine when the main code base reside in the home directory. Now everything working fine after put project under the home directory of the user!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run as admin. Use `sudo npm install`

Comment: I did this but it not fixed that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-g` flag to globally install packages.

Ex: `npm install semver -g`

But to globally install packages, you need elevated privileges. So you have to use `sudo` command.

Ex: `sudo npm install semver -g`